# Fun Python import issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module, pythonpath, modulenotfounderror

I am getting a strange module not found error and I can't seem to grasp why it is happening.

I have a directory structure of:

projects/services/skittles/app/

```
                          database/
                              --__init__.py
                              --testresults.py
                          models/
                              --__init__.py
                              --testresult.py
```

results.py imports:

from app.models.testresult import TestResult, TestRunDetails, Step

app.models.testresult is a file with pydantic models

When I try to run testresults.py directly with:

python testresults.py

I get:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'

I ran:

import os
try:
user_paths = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(os.pathsep)
except KeyError:
user_paths = []

and printing user_paths outputs:

[':/c/Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/projects/']

Please help me understand what is happening. Is the PYTHONPATH incorrect? Seems to me like it is looking into the projects directory, but should it be pointing into the individual folders as well?

Comment: In order for Python to be able to import your package, the directory containing it must be on the Python path. That generally happens in one of three ways: either a) you install your project as a distribution package (preferred), or b) you rely on that directory being your CWD, or c) you fiddle with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` (ugly and precarious, wouldn't advice).

Comment: Can you go into more detail for option b please. Does that mean I would have to be inside the app directory to run files that are importing packages from the app directory?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you can modify your import statement in results.py to specify a relative import path. Since results.py is within the database folder and you're trying to import from app.models.testresult, you can use relative imports like this:
`from ..models.testresult import TestResult, TestRunDetails, Step`